# Video files corruption

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, ssd, video

A few months ago I copied a lot of video files from my laptop to an external HDD, replaced my laptop HDD with an SSD and copied back those files from external HDD to my SSD.

Now some of the video files are corrupted. When I play those files at a specific time they stop playing and when I trying to close the video it freezes the computer until I shut down my computer.

The same thing happens when copying them.

Now when I copy new video files from the other HDD or flash drive after few days they are also corrupted.

I am using windows 7 and an old Dell latitude E6400 laptop.

I don't know what is the problem. I tried antivirus scanning but it also froze my computer. I updated all the drivers but the problem still exists.

Comment: How do you know this issue didn't exist before you transferred the files?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: all the video files that were in my old laptop HDD was ok because they all copied and played fine but since I copied this files from my laptop to an external HDD and replace my laptop HDD with an SSD and copied them back they start corrupting, corrupted files are not copying from one disk to another during copying they freeze my computer

Comment: sounds like a possible failing SSD ... also a possible bad USB port

Comment: That sounds like the external HDD itself is faulty. You might want to check the HDD with crystal disk info or other S.M.A.R.T. software

Comment: what type of video file are they? some specific container/codec combos may be repairable: https://repairit.wondershare.com/video-repair/fix-corrupt-h265-video-files.html https://www.filerepairtool.net/blog/repair-h264-mp4-video-file-mac https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-repair-broken-avi-files-that-wont-play-windows-only/ etc... but check your disks first

Comment: mkv, mp4, h264 and h265

Answer (score 0):

File corruption and a freezing antivirus program (that initially checks everyhting and loads from a lot of locations on the drive thereafter) suggest a broken drive.

Use smartmontools to create a log file of the health status of your drive and post it here.

To avoid writing on a already dammaged drive start a live linux from USB that contains smartmontools already (Gparted, Knoppix and others).

Find your device by running **lsblk**.
Then run **smartctl -a /dev/sda > mylogfile.txt** with admin rights.

The letter "a" in "sda" represents the first drive. Adjust that letter according to what lsblk states.

Hint:
You said you are only using Windows 7. Improper shutdown in dual-boot environment could also cause file corruption.